# create image from divs composite

Tags: php, asp.net

I'd like to have a div as a canvas, where users would choose images to show, out of a list. They will choose what background it would have, icons, and they will upload an image which will appear in this canvas too.

I'm looking for solutions in PHP or ASP.NET.

thansk

Comment: Was there a question here that I missed?

Comment: I'm looking for solutions in PHP or ASP.NET. You could read like: Is there any solutions in PHP or ASP.NET available?

Comment: Haven't tried anything since I haven't found something that conviced me is what I need. Never worked with graphic libraries on those languages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<canvas>` element?

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html - will work only in modern browsers (not IE), but it's very usable, check examples:

- http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/
- http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/images/JS-graffiti.html

Comment: I'll check these out, and give you a return later.

Comment: SkectchPad is awesome! But I can't use in this project something that will not work in IE, unfortunately.